# Column SQL data splitted within commas by guid, data, data relation with other column guids

Tags: php, sql

I have a table called `guild_points_encounter_history` with a column called `guidDamageHealing`.

The data contained in the `guidDamageHealing` column contains three data separated by commas: where the first value is the guid the second value is damaged, and the third value is healing.

Then, I have another column that contains the guids stored, also separated by commas.

I need the guid which is the first value of `guidDamageHealing` to always match with `$playerGuids` and be able to get damage and healing for each MEMBER.guid.

```
    public function getHistoryDetails($historyId)
    {
        $historyData = $this->getHistoryGlobalData($historyId);

        if ($historyData) {
            $bossEntry = $historyData['bossEntry'];
            $playerGuids = $historyData['playerGuids'];
            $leaderGuid = $historyData['leaderGuid'];

            if (strlen($playerGuids) > 0 && !empty($leaderGuid)) {
                $playerGuids = substr($playerGuids, 0, -1);

                $this->connect();

                $result = $this->connection->query("
                    SELECT
                        MEMBER.guid,
                        MEMBER.name,
                        MEMBER.race,
                        MEMBER.class,
                        MEMBER.gender,
                        CASE WHEN MEMBER.race IN (1,3,4,7,11) THEN 'A'
                                WHEN MEMBER.race IN (2,5,6,8,10) THEN 'H'
                                ELSE 'X'
                        END AS faction,
                        CASE WHEN MEMBER.guid = " . $leaderGuid . " THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as isLeader,
                        GUILD.name as guildName,
                        GUILD.guildid,
                        STATS.achievementPoints,
                        STATS.GearScore,
                        STATS.RolPosible,
                        IFNULL(TEMPLATE_LOCALE.Name, TEMPLATE.name) as bossName,
                        HISTORY.ReadableTime,
                        HISTORY.mode as modo,
                        HISTORY.difficulty as dificultad,
                HISTORY.guidDamageHealing
                    FROM
                        characters MEMBER
                    LEFT JOIN
                        guild_member GUILDMEMBER ON (GUILDMEMBER.guid = MEMBER.guid)
                    LEFT JOIN
                        guild_points_encounter_history HISTORY ON (HISTORY.id = " . $historyId . ")
                    LEFT JOIN
                        guild GUILD ON (GUILDMEMBER.guildid = GUILD.guildid)
                    LEFT JOIN
                        character_stats STATS ON (STATS.guid = MEMBER.guid)
                    INNER JOIN
                        world.creature_template TEMPLATE ON (TEMPLATE.entry = " . $bossEntry . ")
                    LEFT JOIN
                        world.creature_template TEMPLATE_LOCALE ON (TEMPLATE.entry = TEMPLATE_LOCALE.entry)
                    WHERE
                        MEMBER.guid IN (" . $playerGuids . ")
                    ORDER BY
                        isLeader DESC
                ");

                if($result && $result->num_rows() > 0)
                {
                    return $result->result_array();
                }

                unset($result);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I need to have damage and healing for each MEMBER.guid of the given `$playerGuids`.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: I think the best solution would be to redesign the table(s) after a quick look through a Relational Database Design Course/Tutorial